Applications of First Passage for Brownian Motions?
In one of my classes, we are learning how to derive the First Passage Time for a Brownian Motion.
We define a Brownian motion $B(t)$, for $t \geq 0$, a stochastic process that satisfies the following properties:

$B(0) = 0$:
For every $t > s \geq 0$, the increment $B(t) - B(s)$ is independent of the past values $B(u)$, for all $u \leq s$.
For every $t > s \geq 0$, the increment $B(t) - B(s)$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $t - s$.

From here, we define the first passage time for a Brownian motion $B(t)$ and a level $a > 0$, the first passage time $T_a$ is:
$$T_a = \inf\{t \geq 0 : B(t) = a\}$$
Since the First Passage Time $T_a$ is a random variable, it has a Probability Distribution. In the case of certain Brownian Motions (e.g. with drift), we learned that $T_a$ has a probability distribution similar to the Inverse Gaussian Distribution:
$$f_{T_a}(t) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}$$
$$E[T_a] = \frac{a^2}{1} = a^2$$
$$Var[T_a] = \frac{(a^2)^2}{1^2} = a^4$$
I have the following question: Why is this First Passage property of the Brownian Motion important?
In all examples, I have only seen it come up in theoretical examples. I tried to ask my professor about how this First Passage property might be used in real life, and my prof told me to "imagine a situation where we are interested in knowing when a stock is first expected to reach a certain value or a portfolio is expected to go below a certain value".
But I am still trying to understand real world examples in which we are specifically interested in analyzing the probability distribution for the first passage time of a Brownian Motion. Does this only come up only in mathematical finance? Or are there other situations where we are interested in analyzing the first passage times of Brownian Motions (or the first passage times of Stochastic Processes in general)?
Much Thanks

PS: If the Brownian Motion is currently at point $a$ and we are interested in the probability distribution of the time needed to pass point $b$ for the first time, the Inverse Gaussian can be adapted like this:

$$f_{T_b}(t) = \frac{b - a}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{(b - a)^2}{2t}}$$
$$E[T_b] = \frac{(b - a)^2}{1} = (b - a)^2$$
$$Var[T_b] = \frac{((b - a)^2)^2}{1^2} = (b - a)^4$$

The Lévy distribution does not have finite mean nor variance. The equations referenced in the post are wrong.

The first passage time is just another word for life time  of an individual starting  a random wolk from a fixed starting point,  if there is an  absorbing boundary.
Applications are always of the type:
Determine the expected time for a chemical detector of a bee, a sphere of r=1mm,  to detect a single molecule  of the fragrance of a certain flower type, starting from a sphere of radius R.
Diffusion constant $D = 10-6 m^2/s$. Diffusion equation $\partial_t \rho= D \ \Delta\ \rho$. Boundary conditions $\rho(R)=1, \rho(r)=0$, Spherical symmetrry.
Determine the number of molecules to be emitted at t=0 in order to get a probability greater 1/2 to have at least one hit.
In finance market eg the first time T_2 to hit the factor 2 before hitting zero, in nuclear physics the half life time, in medicine and life insurance the rest life time expectancy are the most important parameters of stachastic modelling.
